extracting data from golang html/template
In my index.html file there are two {{ define ...}}.
{{define "options"}}

    {{block "settings" .}}
    {{end}}
{{end}}

{{define "base"}}

...

{{ end }}

In any other html file I want to be able to get the settings specified in the options.
{{template "options" .}}
    {{define "settings"}}
    {{options "paginate_by" 7}}
{{end}}

How to extract this data from the template? I extract all templates before launching the site

What do you mean by "extract"? You want to execute it elsewhere? You want the template rendering result as a string?

get "paginate_by" 7 and parse it into a structure

From where do you want to get it? From the template source? See How to get a map or list of template 'actions' from a parsed template?
